# Why I can't add/remove body class by using use:action Svelte

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I have this function

```
    const bodyClass = (node) => {
        if (open && !node.classList.contains("is-search-show")) {
            node.classList.add("is-search-show");
       
        } else if (
            !open &&
            node.classList.contains("is-search-show")
        ) {
            node.classList.remove("is-search-show");
        }
    };
```

A Svelte body element added in the component

`<svelte:body use:bodyClass use:HandleClickMenu />`

but I don't know why it did not work when `open = true`, there's no 'is-search-show' class added to body. Please help me to understand that. Thanks

I tried to change `node.classList.add("is-search-show");` to `window.document.body.classList.add("is-search-show");` but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action code is *not* reactive. You have to:

- Return an object with an `update` function
- Pass any dependencies as arguments to the action, otherwise `update` will not be called

[See docs](https://svelte.dev/docs/element-directives#use-action)

E.g.

```js
const bodyClass = node => {
    const update = () => node.classList.toggle('is-search-show', open);
    update();

    return { update };
}
```

```html
<svelte:body use:bodyClass={open} />
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/48470a47342d47e7a9687b4f125a3194?version=4.2.8)

(You also can return a `destroy` function for cleanup.)